# Finding number of collections in turtle file

Tags: rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

First I extract object from statement and then try to use one of the functions `isBag() isSeq() and isAlt()` but it gives error

```
 "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isBag()
  location: variable object of type RDFNode"
```

Comment: The error is unclear - runtime? compile time?  If the latter, it's a problem with the classpath.

Comment: Perhaps it would be insightful to give a sample from your data, and then a minimal Java code snippet that produces this error. Also perhaps, the version of the Jena library that you are using...

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the answer and to try the techniques described in there?  It's been a few days, and with a couple of upvotes; if it's _not_ a suitable answer, we can try to update it to address your problem.  If it _does_ work for you, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225437) to let other users know that it worked for you (and to give the answerer a bit of reputation as a reward, and also some for yourself).

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting an error like:

> cannot find symbol symbol: method `isBag()` location: variable object of type `RDFNode`

then you're getting the subject of the statement in a way that's giving you (in terms of the Java source) an `RDFNode` instead of a `Resource`.  This is surprising, because [Statement.getSubject()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Statement.html#getSubject%28%29) returns a `Resource`.  This means that it sounds like you're doing something like:

```java
RDFNode subject = statement.getSubject();
if ( subject.isBag() ) { … }
```

However, you can't do

```java
Resource subject = statement.getSubject();
if ( subject.isBag() ) { … }
```

either, because `isBag`, etc., aren't defined in `Resource`, either;  they come from [Container](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Container.html).  What you *can* do, however, is ask whether the Resource (or RDFNode) [`canAs`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/RDFNode.html#canAs%28java.lang.Class%29)`( Container.class )`, and if it is can be viewed as a Container, use the `as` method to get the Container, which you can then check for more specific subtypes:

```java
Resource subject = statement.getSubject();
if ( subject.canAs( Container.class ) ) { 
  Container container = subject.as( Container.class );
  if ( container.isBag() ) {
    …
  }
  else if ( container.isAlt() ) {
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: yes I tried this approach, its giving casting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl to com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Container
 at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3084)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:154)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:31)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.Polymorphic.asInternal(Polymorphic.java:62)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.as(EnhNode.java:107)
 at rdfparser.Rdfparser.main(Rdfparser.java:59)

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to diagnose that error.  I'd expect that unless there's a bug a in Jena, if `subject.canAs( Container.class )` is true, then you shouldn't have a problem with `Container container = subject.as( Container.class );`.  However, perhaps `canAs` doesn't work for `Container.class`, and you'll need to check whether it canAs( Bag.class ), canAs( Alt.class ), etc.